# I get the same output in for loop

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import pandas as pd

s=Service("C:\selenium driver\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

companies_names = []
persons_names = []
phones_numbers = []
locations = []
opening_hours = []
descriptions = []
websites_links = []
all_profiles = []

driver.get("https://www.saveface.co.uk/search/")

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

blocks = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='result clientresult']")

for block in range(30):
    
    company_name = blocks[block].find_element(By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='resulttitle']").text.strip()
    companies_names.append(company_name)

    person_name = blocks[block].find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[@class='name_wrapper']").text.strip()
    persons_names.append(person_name)

    phone_number = blocks[block].find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='searchContact phone']").text.strip()
    phones_numbers.append(phone_number)

    location = blocks[block].find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='cls_loc']").text.strip()
    locations.append(location)

    opening_hour = blocks[block].find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='opening-hours']").text.strip()
    opening_hours.append(opening_hour)

    profile = blocks[block].find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='visitpage']").get_attribute("href")
    all_profiles.append(profile)
    
    print(company_name, person_name, phone_number, location, opening_hour, profile)

    if block == 29:
        two_page = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='facetwp-page']")
        two_page.click()
        
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)

        blocks = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='result clientresult']")

for i in range(len(all_profiles)):
    
    driver.get(all_profiles[i])

    description = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='desc-text-left']").text.strip()
    descriptions.append(description)

    website_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='visitwebsite website']").get_attribute("href")
    websites_links.append(website_link)        


driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.close()

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "company_name": companies_names,
        "person_name": persons_names,
        "phone_number": phones_numbers,
        "location": locations,
        "opening_hour": opening_hours,
        "description": descriptions,
        "website_link": websites_links,
        "profile_on_saveface": all_profiles
    }
)

df.to_csv('saveface.csv',index=False)
#print(df)
```

This is the result:

```
The Hartley Clinic Clinic Contact: Ailing Jeavons 01256 856289 , , Fleet, RG27 8NZ Monday 8:30 — 17:00 Tuesday 8:30 — 19:00 Wednesday 8:30— 17:00 Thursday 8:30 — 17:00 Friday 8:30 — 15:00 Saturday 9:00 — 17:00 Sunday Closed https://www.saveface.co.uk/clinic/the-hartley-clinic/
The Hartley Clinic Clinic Contact: Ailing Jeavons 01256 856289 , , Fleet, RG27 8NZ Monday 8:30 — 17:00 Tuesday 8:30 — 19:00 Wednesday 8:30— 17:00 Thursday 8:30 — 17:00 Friday 8:30 — 15:00 Saturday 9:00 — 17:00 Sunday Closed https://www.saveface.co.uk/clinic/the-hartley-clinic/
The Hartley Clinic Clinic Contact: Ailing Jeavons 01256 856289 , , Fleet, RG27 8NZ Monday 8:30 — 17:00 Tuesday 8:30 — 19:00 Wednesday 8:30— 17:00 Thursday 8:30 — 17:00 Friday 8:30 — 15:00 Saturday 9:00 — 17:00 Sunday Closed https://www.saveface.co.uk/clinic/the-hartley-clinic/
The Hartley Clinic Clinic Contact: Ailing Jeavons 01256 856289 , , Fleet, RG27 8NZ Monday 8:30 — 17:00 Tuesday 8:30 — 19:00 Wednesday 8:30— 17:00 Thursday 8:30 — 17:00 Friday 8:30 — 15:00 Saturday 9:00 — 17:00 Sunday Closed https://www.saveface.co.uk/clinic/the-hartley-clinic/
The Hartley Clinic Clinic Contact: Ailing Jeavons 01256 856289 , , Fleet, RG27 8NZ Monday 8:30 — 17:00 Tuesday 8:30 — 19:00 Wednesday 8:30— 17:00 Thursday 8:30 — 17:00 Friday 8:30 — 15:00 Saturday 9:00 — 17:00 Sunday Closed https://www.saveface.co.uk/clinic/the-hartley-clinic/
The Hartley Clinic Clinic Contact: Ailing Jeavons 01256 856289 , , Fleet, RG27 8NZ Monday 8:30 — 17:00 Tuesday 8:30 — 19:00 Wednesday 8:30— 17:00 Thursday 8:30 — 17:00 Friday 8:30 — 15:00 Saturday 9:00 — 17:00 Sunday Closed https://www.saveface.co.uk/clinic/the-hartley-clinic/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restric the search within a subtree rooted at the context node, your expression should start with `.//` so you have to replace `//` with `.//` in each of the commands

```
... = blocks[block].find_element(...)
```

The meaning of `//` is to search the document from the document's root, ignoring the context node `blocks[block]` altogether.

Moreover, notice that not all the blocks have a location as you can see from this image

[image]

in this case

```
location = blocks[block].find_element(By.XPATH, "//li[@class='cls_loc']")
```

will raise a `NoSuchElementException`. To avoid this you have to put the command in a `try...except...` block

## UPDATE

Scraping 400 blocks with selenium takes about 1 minute on my computer, I tried with BeautifulSoup and it just takes less than 1 second! The slow part is to scrape the profiles, because for each of them we have to download a new webpage, however is still way faster with BeautifulSoup.

So I write a script without using selenium, just BeautifulSoup (you can install by running `pip install beautifulsoup4` in the terminal)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.saveface.co.uk/search/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")

css_selector = {
    'company name' : ".title",
    'person name'  : ".name_wrapper",
    'phone number' : ".phone",
    'location'     : ".cls_loc",
    'opening hours': ".opening-hours",
    'profile link' : ".visitpage",
}
data = {key:[] for key in list(css_selector)+['description','website link']}
number_of_pages = int(str(soup).split('total_pages":')[1].split('}')[0])

for page in range(2,number_of_pages+2):
    
    blocks = soup.select('.clientresult')
    for idx,block in enumerate(blocks):
        print(f'blocks {idx+1}/{len(blocks)}',end='\r')
        for key in list(css_selector):
            try:
                if 'link' in key:
                    data[key] += [ block.select_one(css_selector[key])['href'] ]
                else:
                    data[key] += [ block.select_one(css_selector[key]).text.strip().replace('\r\n',', ') ]
            except AttributeError:
                data[key] += ['*missing value*']

    if page <= number_of_pages:
        print('\nloading page', page)
        url_page = f'{url}?fwp_paged={page}'
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url_page).text, "html.parser")

print('\nno more pages to load, moving to scrape profile links...')

for idx,url in enumerate(data['profile link']):
    
    print(f"profile link {idx+1}/{len(data['profile link'])}  ",end='\r')
    soup_profile = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
    try:
        data['description'] += [soup_profile.select_one('.clinicContent > .description').text.strip()]
    except AttributeError:
        data['description'] += ['*missing value*']
    try:
        data['website link'] += [soup_profile.select_one('.visitwebsite')['href']]
    except AttributeError:
        data['website link'] += ['*missing value*']
```

Output (it took about 8 minutes to complete the execution)

```
blocks 400/400
loading page 2
blocks 109/109
no more pages to load, moving to scrape profile links...
profile link 509/509
```

Then you can easily create the dataframe by running `pd.DataFrame(data)`

[image]

Comment: take a look at the new code

Comment: It is very cool and practical, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

this is the new code
but it returns the same output on every page why:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import pandas as pd

s=Service("C:\selenium driver\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

companies_names = []
persons_names = []
phones_numbers = []
locations = []
opening_hours = []
descriptions = []
websites_links = []
all_profiles = []

driver.get("https://www.saveface.co.uk/search/")

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

pages = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//a[@class='facetwp-page']")

for page in range(len(pages)+1):

    blocks = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='result clientresult']")
    
    for block in range(10):

        try:    
            company_name = blocks[block].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//h3[@class='resulttitle']").text.strip()
            companies_names.append(company_name)
        except:
            companies_names.append("Not found on the site")

        try:    
            person_name = blocks[block].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//p[@class='name_wrapper']").text.strip()
            persons_names.append(person_name)
        except:
            persons_names.append("Not found on the site")

        try:    
            phone_number = blocks[block].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='searchContact phone']").text.strip()
            phones_numbers.append(phone_number)
        except:
            phones_numbers.append("Not found on the site")

        try:    
            location = blocks[block].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//li[@class='cls_loc']").text.strip()
            locations.append(location)
        except:
            locations.append("Not found on the site")

        try:    
            opening_hour = blocks[block].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//li[@class='opening-hours']").text.strip()
            opening_hours.append(opening_hour)
        except:
            opening_hours.append("Not found on the site")
            
        try:    
            profile = blocks[block].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[@class='visitpage']").get_attribute("href")
            all_profiles.append(profile)
        except:
            all_profiles.append("Not found on the site")
                
    two_page = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[@class='facetwp-page']")
    two_page.click()
            
for i in range(len(all_profiles)):

    try:
        
        driver.get(all_profiles[i])

        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        
        try:    
            description = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//div[@class='desc-text-left']").text.strip()
            descriptions.append(description)
        except:
            descriptions.append("Not found on the site")
            
        try:    
            website_link = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a[@class='visitwebsite website']").get_attribute("href")
            websites_links.append(website_link)        
        except:
            websites_links.append("Not found on the site")

    except:
        descriptions.append("Not found on the site")
        websites_links.append("Not found on the site")

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.close()

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "company_name": companies_names,
        "person_name": persons_names,
        "phone_number": phones_numbers,
        "location": locations,
        "opening_hour": opening_hours,
        "description": descriptions,
        "website_link": websites_links,
        "profile_on_saveface": all_profiles
    }
)

df.to_csv('saveface.csv',index=False)
print(df)
```

Comment: Why you say so? I tried to run the code and `person_name` contains all different names `['Clinic Contact: Chloe Cameron',
 'Clinic Contact: Lorna Smith',
 'Clinic Contact: Daniela Greaves',
 'Clinic Contact: Janine Warner',
 'Clinic Contact: Janine Warner',
 'Clinic Contact: Deby Rowbottom',
 'Clinic Contact: Irena Daniels',
 'Clinic Contact: Ahmed Shaheen',
 'Clinic Contact: Ahmed Shaheen',
 'Clinic Contact: Dr Victoria Manning']`

Comment: But after ten of the person_name on the first page, it returns the same ten when entering on the second page

Comment: Because when you click the next page button you have to wait some seconds for the new blocks to load, while in your code you immediately go to scrape the data but new blocks have not loaded yet. Try to add `time.sleep(10)` after the command `two_page.click()`

Comment: Anyway, I'm trying using BeautifulSoup and it is way faster than selenium to scrape the data: 1 second vs 1 minute

Comment: I updated the answer with full code using BeautifulSoup, check it out and let me know

Comment: beside `time.slep` you can use `EC` conditionals for explicitly waiting, first you need to import module, then use one of `wait until visibility of all elements or presence of all elements`

Comment: I saw the new code and it's great, sorry for the delay